# How php time is related to hardware clock (hwclock)?

Tags: php, linux, timezone

I have correctly set timezone to Europe/Dublin and daylight is true but I receive wrong hour - 1 hour earlier. 
`echo date("H:i:s"); // returns 11:03:49,` should be 12:03:49.
Linux system time is set correctly but maybe I have to change something in hardware time? What should I do to gain correct time in php?

```
# hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
Using /dev interface to clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 1507541250 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 1507541250 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on UTC time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2017/10/09 10:03:49
Hw clock time : 2017/10/09 10:03:49 = 1507543429 seconds since 1969
Mon 09 Oct 2017 12:03:49 PM CEST  -0.094111 seconds
```

Comment: Have you set the timezone in PHP.ini?

Comment: Yes it is set both in php.ini and php script

Comment: what does date('r') show you?

Comment: Shows: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 15:06:52 +0100, but now is 16.06

Comment: Odd. indicates UTC time and correctly identifies + 1 hour (+0100) for your Timezone. I know you said you've set time zone in your scripts. How did you do this? `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Dublin");` Sorry am out of ideas.

Comment: Exactly in this way.